# Ruby split pipes in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have put the data from a file into an array, then I am just staying with the data I want of that array which looks like follows:

Basically what I want, is to access each column independently. As the file will keep changing I don't want something hard coded, I would have done it already :).

`Element0: |     data     | address  | type | source | disable |`

`Element1: |   0x000001   | 0x123456 |  in  |    D   |   yes   |`

`Element2: |   0x0d0f00   | 0xffffff |  out |    M   |   yes   |`

`Element3: |   0xe00ab4   | 0xaefbd1 |  in  |    E   |   no    |`

I have tried with the regexp `/\|\s+.*\s+\|/`it prints just few lines (it removes the data I care of). I also tried with `/\|.*\|/` and it prints all empty.
I have googled the split method and I know that this is happening it is because of the `.*` removing the data I care of. I have also tried with the regexp `\|\s*\|` but it prints the whole line. I have tried with many regexp's but at this moment I can't think of a way to solve this. 
Any recommendation?

```
`line_ary = ary_element.split(/\|\s.*\|/)
    unless  line_ary.nil?  puts line_ary`
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? As @krock suggests, use the `CSV` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [csv class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) instead of trying to regex parse it.  Something like this will do:

```
require 'csv'
data = CSV.read('data.csv', 'r', col_sep: '|')
```

You can access rows and columns as a 2 dimentional array, e.g. to access row 2, column 4: `data[1][3]`.

If for example you just wanted to print the address column for all rows you could do this instead:

```
CSV.foreach('data.csv', col_sep: '|') do |row|
    puts row[2]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use a CSV parser for this but if you want to use a regex and you're sure that you'll never have `|` inside one of the column values, then you want to say:

```
row = line.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
```

so that the whitespace on either side of the pipe becomes part of the delimiter. For example:

```
> 'Element0: |     data     | address  | type | source | disable |'.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
 => ["Element0:", "data", "address", "type", "source", "disable"] 
> 'Element1: |   0x000001   | 0x123456 |  in  |    D   |   yes   |'.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
 => ["Element1:", "0x000001", "0x123456", "in", "D", "yes"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split together with strip might be the easiest option. Have you tried something like this?

```
"Element3:...".split(/\|/).collect(&:strip)
```